# Is it ok to include references to a book in a report even if I have not quoted the book in the text?

Tags: citations

I am writing a report based on activities performed during my internship as a  webmaster. It is to be written in the format of a thesis in APA format. In the report I reference  examples that I found on the Internet. However, I have been asked to include references to books.

Is it okay to include references to books in my thesis-style report even if I have not quoted these books?

Comment: i cannot parse "have quotes on the text".

Comment: I attempted to clean up the English a bit. Hopefully it still captures your question. If not, then edit further.

Answer (score 1):

Felix, the short answer is no. Though you can reference a book from which you did not include a verbatim quote, but you must not ref a book you have not read and used.

Books have a legitimate role even in the life of a webmaster. I am sure the information you looked up on Stackoverflow is also covered in books like, for example [Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux-7-System_Administrators_Guide](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/pdf/System_Administrators_Guide/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux-7-System_Administrators_Guide-en-US.pdf), [Modern PHP: New Features and Good Practices](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1491905018) or [Hacking: Beginner to Expert Guide to Computer Hacking](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01HVVFDD4). Have half a dozen of these substantial reference volumes at hand and use them. Your teachers aim to build a practice they you will follow later on, the practice of using several reliable sources for the information and knowledge you gather.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, i ask the same to my teacher and all they said is "add book references" i'm going to modify the text to add the appropriate references.

Comment: If the question is "Is it okay to include references to books in my thesis-style report even if I have not quoted these books?", your first paragraph reads like the short answer should actually be *yes*.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper - Absolutely, provided you actually read those books, you indeed must reference them. What I'd try to avoid is to bloat a ref list to impress people without having earned the privilege.

Answer (score 1):

Although there are a couple of people who practice this taboo of adding references without actually referring them, it is ill-advised.

Nevertheless, references to established books add credibility to your work.If your teacher insists to refer a book, then *refer it* in your work, then cite it.

Referring it doesn't necessarily mean you *have* to include in your work any textual content that the cited material provides. You may refer [here](http://www.writing-with-confidence.org/citing-sources.html) and [here](http://library.albany.edu/infolit/citesources) to get an idea of when you could/should cite a material. In addition, you may appropriately cite a source

- if you believe that the content of the source would help the reader to understand the foundation/extension of your work.
- if you have derived an idea based on the content mentioned in the source.
- if the source supports the claim you wish to establish
- if it contains an application/use-case of any method you propose

Comment: *Why* is it ill-advised? I have been told numerous times that scanning a bibliography of a paper simply to find a list of thematically related works is a good idea when trying to get an overview of a topic. For this use-case, it seems beneficial to have more references, even though some might not be mentioned in the text. For any other use-case, I do not see how there are any negative effects.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Actually, I support your claim. I meant people who didn't even open a page in the book, but cited it for the mere sake of reference count and portray false credibility. I'll make the points clear in the post.

Comment: Aah, sorry then - I suppose the verb "referring" is ambiguous in this context.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Agreed